# putting a statement into a python function doesn't work

Tags: python, dataframe

I tried to change one column's value using another column in pandas dataframe. e.g. when the target column is null or has value of "No", and the source column is not null, the value in target column will be replaced by the value from the source column.
So the following works:

```
dataFrame['daily1EP'] = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x['daily8EP'] if (pd.notnull(x['daily8EP']) and (pd.isnull(x['daily1EP']) or x['daily1EP'] == 'No')) else x['daily1EP'], axis=1)
```

Here 'daily1EP' is the target column, and 'daily8EP' is the source column. Then I created a function as follows:

```
def merge_two_columns(df, target_col, source_col):
    df[target_col] = df.apply(lambda x: x[source_col] if (pd.notnull(x[source_col]) and (pd.isnull(x[target_col]) or x[target_col] == 'No')) else x[target_col],axis=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Then I tried to run the following, it didn't work.

```
dataFrame = merge_two_columns(dataFrame, 'daily1EP', 'daily8EP')
```

any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a) off topic and (belongs to SO) and b) author provided own answer which is inconclusive

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. I messed up the `source_col` and `target_col` in the function.

Comment: If you could solve your problem please accept your own answer so the question does not remain open. Ideally, describe the solution in more detail so other users with similar problems might benefit from it in the future.